# Adafruit LCD Going blank when using static gun

Tags: raspberry-pi, lcd, esd

I'm having a problem with an [Adafruit touch screen Module](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-8-tft-touch-shield-v2/downloads).

When I use a spark gun (set to 20kV) on a grounded metal plate (placed a meter away from the DUT) after a few tries, the screen goes blank.
Initially when this happened the touch screen (which is on I2C bus) hangs up. So I put ESD suppression diodes on all data lines (the touch screen is on I2C and the LCD is on SPI). This seemed to have fixed the I2C hang up. However, the backlight seem to whitewash the LCD screen.

The LCD is on a shielded cable which is approx. 1m in length.
The whole system works on 3V3. The ESD diodes (AQ3102-02HTG) have a built in 5V Zener Diode.

When I scope the power and data lines, I can see that there are voltage spikes of approx. 30V-50V for a duration of approx. 56ns - coinciding with the spark gun trigger.

Since all the lines have ESD diodes (on the main processor side and LCD side) I thought that this would have stopped the LCD controller from resetting. However, I was wrong as the LCD still shows a White screen of death. (Although the I2C is still working).

Can anyone please help out on this issue?

Please note that the main processor in a plastic box which is coated in anti-static paint.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: Well, the LCD module itself has some circuitry which might not be sufficiently shielded too.

Comment: Well that may be true. The LCD is in a plastic box which is made by us. Would it help if the interior of the box is coated in anti-static paint?

Comment: I do not think antistatic coating will do anything. It's not the statics the problem here but EMI. The spark gun is emitting a strong electromagnetic pulse which is picked up by the conductors acting as antenna. You need a grounded shielding.

Comment: The whole assembly is in a plastic enclosure. The shield is currently connected to the Ground of the unit (which is the main Ground from the Lithium Battery)
What more could be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "shield"?  Do you have a Faraday cage around the electronics?

Comment: I meant that the 1m cable is a shielded cable. This shield is connected to the Ground of the Main unit. This shield would be considered as the Faraday cage. Am I right?
I was thinking that the anti-static coating would act as a faraday cage for the unit.

Comment: Sorry, you should probably draw some sketch of your setup. It is not clear what is "Main unit", what is DUT, how they are interconnected and what exactly you are doing to them.

Comment: Schematics and diagrams are needed. One meter I2C can easily work if designed properly, but having a 1 meter SPI, I would not expect it to work reliably at all.

Comment: I shall do a schematic diagram and share it ASAP

Comment: Using a "fine metallic grid" wired to "ground" around the LCD module would help a little.

Comment: The EMI will hit the silicon of your ICs and PCB tracks as well as cables and connections. @EugeneSh. correctly said that you need decent shielding around the display to stop this. (a) You can experiment by putting a large earthed (thick short wire to mains plug earth) mesh between the display and gun and see how the susceptibility distance changes with and without it. (b) Try adding resistors (pulling up or down as suits) on each signal (try 3K3) and a load resistor across the power rail (try 3K3) then test again. (c) SPI up 1 m is asking a lot unless you use a low bus clock frequency.

Comment: I already have 3.01k pullup resistors on the I2C Lines. 
I only found out that although the multi core cable is shielded, the shield does not cover the entire cable. So what I'll be doing is try wrapping aluminium foil around the exposed conductor and do an iterative test. 
I may end up with a unit fully covered in Ali foil (hope it doesn't come to that). 
I shall update shortly.

Comment: I've had mixed results with the test. I actually ended up covering almost the whole unit in Aluminium foil.

Comment: I've had mixed results with the test. I actually ended up covering almost the whole unit in Aluminium foil.
The system sometimes dies (white screen) almost instantly but sometimes, I have to attack it with the spark gun for a good few minutes before it dies.
Initially I tried the test with the LCD covered completely in Aluminium Foil, however this didn't work (I had to test this by putting a small hole in the foil to see the screen).
Then I removed some of the foil (exposing just the LCD) and the results are the same. 
It should be noted that the foil is Grounded to the Battery Ground.

Comment: I've edited the post with the circuit diagram.
As you can see, the 10 way Molex Connector is the one to which a 1m cable and LCD screen is connected. Since the LCD is a bought in module, there is nothing we can do on the LCD PCB. However, the 10 way cable is plugged onto an adapter board which then sits on the LCD module. If you could suggest any additional circuitry, then I can do it on this PCB.